# How to open twitter page in twitter app from my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, url, twitter

The page I want to open using twitter app:

> https://twitter.com/#!/PAGE

To open twitter app I use the following code:

```
NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"twitter://https://twitter.com/#!/PAGE"]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
```

But this code doesn't seem to work as expected, I got only twitter app launched without the page which i want to show.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are looking for the following url:

```
twitter:///user?screen_name=PAGE
```

Note that Twitter is not installed on all devices. You should check the result of `openURL` method. If it fails, open the page in Safari with regular url.

Comment: There are three forward slashes shown in the URL for this answer.  Using two worked for me.

Comment: What would this url look like for an intent like `https://twitter.com/intent?text=hello`?

Answer (score 14):

I know its quite a late response to this question and I agree that, Murat's answer is absolutely correct.
Simply add a check as follows:

```
NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"twitter:///user?screen_name=PAGE]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlApp]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
    }
```

I hope this helps someone. Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 14):

The following code opens twitter page on twitter app if it is already installed, otherwise opens twitter on safari:

```
NSURL *twitterURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?screen_name=username"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:twitterURL])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:twitterURL];
else
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.twitter.com/username"]];
```

***Don't forget to replace 'username' with your name.***

Comment: Also remember to add LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to info.plist.

Answer (score 6):

This is the full code required in Swift. I am using Swift 4 but i believe it is the same for Swift 3.

```
let Username =  "YOUR_USERNAME_HERE" 
let appURL = NSURL(string: "twitter:///user?screen_name=\(Username)")!
let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://twitter.com/\(Username)")!
let application = UIApplication.shared
if application.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
      application.open(appURL as URL)
    } else {
        // if Twitter app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
        application.open(webURL as URL)
    }
```

Don't forget to add the Info keys needed to use `canOpenURL`:
[image: Info Keys Needed]

Comment: Can you tell how do you find that? Is there any official documentation

Answer (score 2):

@Alexey: If you just want to know how to launch twitter from your application do this:

```
NSURL *urlApp = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"twitter://"]];
   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlApp]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlApp];
   }else{
        UIAlertView *appMissingAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Twitter App Not Installed!" message:@"Please install the Twitter App on your iPhone." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
        [appMissingAlertView show];
        [appMissingAlertView release];
    }
```