# Sharing data to social media in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an app in which i want to share specific data to social media like facebook,twitter,pinterest etc once the user clicks on the social icon. I have already used react native link which sends me to the pages of these platforms. But i want to share data to these once clicked. I have done this for whatsapp which is like this:

```js
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                let url = 'whatsapp://send?text=${hello}&phone=${01753362960}';
                Linking.openURL(url).then((data) => {
                  console.log('open whatsapp', data)
                }).catch(() => {
                  console.log('App not installed')
                });
              }} >
            <Icon name='logo-whatsapp' style={{color: '#395894', fontSize: 30, marginRight: 10}}/>
     </TouchableOpacity>
```

I have done this for twitter also. But when that icon is clicked it shows the alert that the app is not installed although it was installed on my device.It was like:

```js
 let url = 'twitter://send?text=hello this is checked'
```

How can i do this for other social media platforms?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8975424/6008453)? Why do you think that twitter has `/send` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For twitter please use this,

```
let url = 'twitter://post?message=${yourMsg}'
```

Comment: I want to do it for facebook, google plus, pinterest and  linkedIn  also. Can i just  edit  the url and replace the name twitter?

Comment: No, you need to check first, there must be different URL for different social media.

Comment: @Kazi Rahamatullah you please go for react-native-share package, though its a  bit late answer but i just look at it, now react-native-share is much mature package.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share

This way the user can chose what app he wants to share to based on apps installed on users device

Answer (score 0):

react-native-share is a good package to use for making some stuff share at different platforms.
Back in early 2019 this package wasn't this much mature, but now it's really usefull.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share

Have a look at here.
Thanks.